# how to uninstall gcc-code-assist?

Tags: gcc, emacs, autocomplete

I download gcc-code-assist from [here](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/#Downloads), then do "make" and "sudo make install". After I configured my emacs, i found that it can't help me complete large project as my expectation.
I want to uninstall it, however, "make uninstall" report "the uninstall target is not supported in this tree". What can I do if I want to uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the settings from your `.emacs` and continue using gcc-sense/gcc-code-assist as a compiler.  If you need it uninstalled for some reason, you might have to remove the files by hand.

Comment: I don't know what files does it install for me. So that's mean I have to research its Makefile?

Comment: Yes.  Or, you could look at the files that `make` builds.  They should  be in a bin/ or in the same directory as the sources.

Comment: I think it's better to write an email to its author :P